# What time zones does Outlook 2007 support in iCalendar invites?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, icalendar, ical4j

I understand Outlook only "[partially](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)" conforms to the standard.  Does Microsoft have a published spec on what they do conform with?

I need a list of the available time zone id's I can use for Outlook meeting invites.

I'm using [ical4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) to build my invite.  I found the [ical4j-zoneinfo-outlook](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=ZoneInfoOutlook) project, and it works for the basic America/Chicago and America/New_York time zones.  Overall I can't get a list of the complete available id's from this library, and it won't support basic "GMT-6:00".

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get a full list of timezone ids for iCal4j is to check the http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook website. This is the source for ical4j's timezones.

Note that you still need to either manually or programmatically traverse the site to get all the valid ids.

Comment: I guess your right, not ideal though :(.  Maybe I'm just asking for to much.